# Apache and Other Services Hung

Tags: linux, apache2, lamp, freeze

I have a production LAMP server on Gentoo that's been running a personal intranet website. Since yesterday afternoon, it's hanging shortly after any connection; the relatively small login page loads fine, but upon logging in which involves a lot of MySQL queries and data, it hangs indefinitely.

SSH is still able to connect but oddly, that suddenly hangs too after a few pages' worth of characters are transmitted. Thus to get the below information, I have to keep logging back in. I tried /etc/init.d/apache2 restart and /etc/init.d/mysql restart, and then did a full reboot of the system; yet alas the problem persists. Details follow.

Top:

```
top - 12:23:52 up  1:34,  2 users,  load average: 0.16, 0.09, 0.06 Tasks:  81 total,   1 running,  80 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,
0.0%st Mem:   3920788k total,   123476k used,  3797312k free,     4676k buffers Swap:  1227772k total,        0k used,  1227772k free,   48524k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND   447 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.16 khubd
    1 root      20   0  2020  640  568 S    0  0.0   0:00.51 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u:0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.69 kworker/0:1
```

Apache logs show the usual hacking attempts:

```
# tail -50 /var/log/apache2/error_log
[Mon Mar 17 19:03:48 2014] [error] [client 116.58.240.169] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/pma
[Mon Mar 17 19:03:48 2014] [error] [client 116.58.240.169] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/myadmin
[Tue Mar 18 05:58:42 2014] [error] [client 202.53.8.82] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/admin.cgi
[Tue Mar 18 07:19:42 2014] [error] [client 74.63.220.132] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/phpTest
[Tue Mar 18 07:19:43 2014] [error] [client 74.63.220.132] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/phpMyAdmin
[Tue Mar 18 07:19:43 2014] [error] [client 74.63.220.132] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/pma
[Tue Mar 18 07:19:44 2014] [error] [client 74.63.220.132] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/myadmin
[Tue Mar 18 08:24:16 2014] [error] [client 222.5.204.73] invalid request-URI \xcc\\\xa4/\x83\x8f\x90:\x84\x90\x0f\xc4\x8dfe\xecb\x94v\x1f[\xd7Z\x95$X\xaby\x13k\x88\xf2\xeb\xf7\x1b\xfc\xe8a\xff
[Tue Mar 18 08:29:49 2014] [error] [client 76.3.191.245] invalid request-URI
[Tue Mar 18 08:38:00 2014] [error] [client 35.2.240.149] invalid request-URI
[Tue Mar 18 08:50:52 2014] [error] [client 173.26.148.34] invalid request-URI
[Tue Mar 18 10:57:48 2014] [error] [client 110.175.79.216] invalid request-URI
[Tue Mar 18 10:57:53 2014] [error] [client 110.248.140.59] invalid request-URI D\xe8\x91a\xbc\xe5WZ\xd0C]\x9f~\xb5\x89\bd\x9e"[w,\xc6\xd9\xde\x8b]#JJ\xbf\x12
[Tue Mar 18 14:24:54 2014] [error] [client 108.14.2.113] invalid request-URI
[Tue Mar 18 14:40:08 2014] [error] [client 86.217.136.41] invalid request-URI \x94FI-\x02;4JVOV\x0f\xba\b
[Tue Mar 18 14:45:42 2014] [error] [client 98.119.127.76] invalid request-URI
[Tue Mar 18 15:25:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[Tue Mar 18 15:25:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/apple-touch-icon.png
[Tue Mar 18 15:25:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png
[Tue Mar 18 15:25:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png
[Tue Mar 18 15:25:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[Tue Mar 18 15:25:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/apple-touch-icon.png
[Tue Mar 18 16:20:45 2014] [error] [client 103.24.32.14] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/phpTest
[Tue Mar 18 16:20:46 2014] [error] [client 103.24.32.14] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/phpMyAdmin
[Tue Mar 18 16:20:46 2014] [error] [client 103.24.32.14] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/pma
[Tue Mar 18 16:20:46 2014] [error] [client 103.24.32.14] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/myadmin
[Tue Mar 18 16:40:58 2014] [error] [client 122.170.93.35] invalid request-URI
[Tue Mar 18 16:57:54 2014] [error] [client 124.107.151.190] invalid request-URI
[Tue Mar 18 17:36:17 2014] [error] [client 68.147.250.90] invalid request-URI \x1d\x1e;&\x9e\xd2\xa8\xc2GNQ\\
[Tue Mar 18 23:38:20 2014] [error] [client 92.240.68.153] request failed: error reading the headers
[Wed Mar 19 02:52:43 2014] [error] [client 162.213.24.36] File does not exist: /var/www/mysite/CFIDE
[Wed Mar 19 06:26:06 2014] [error] [client 5.249.137.202] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin
[Wed Mar 19 06:26:07 2014] [error] [client 5.249.137.202] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin
[Wed Mar 19 06:26:07 2014] [error] [client 5.249.137.202] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin
[Wed Mar 19 06:26:09 2014] [error] [client 5.249.137.202] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin
[Wed Mar 19 06:26:15 2014] [error] [client 5.249.137.202] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin
[Wed Mar 19 07:48:28 2014] [error] [client 201.161.37.93] File does not exist: /var/www/crownware/manager
[Wed Mar 19 09:27:08 2014] [error] [client 113.184.228.73] invalid request-URI \xad_X\xdf\x9aIM6x\x01ti\xf6Ko\xebi
[Wed Mar 19 09:36:06 2014] [error] [client 162.213.24.36] File does not exist: /var/www/crownware/CFIDE
[Wed Mar 19 10:28:15 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Mar 19 10:28:17 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.0j PHP/5.4.6--pl0-gentoo configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 19 10:43:31 2014] [error] [client 5.249.137.202] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin
[Wed Mar 19 10:43:31 2014] [error] [client 5.249.137.202] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin
[Wed Mar 19 10:43:35 2014] [error] [client 5.249.137.202] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin
[Wed Mar 19 10:43:35 2014] [error] [client 5.249.137.202] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin
[Wed Mar 19 10:43:36 2014] [error] [client 5.249.137.202] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin
[Wed Mar 19 10:47:16 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Mar 19 10:49:32 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.0j PHP/5.4.6--pl0-gentoo configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 19 10:53:45 2014] [error] [client 65.60.209.141] Invalid URI in request \x13\xe0\x94\xc4\xa4o\xd1\xd3*\xe0\xe7\x1a\xce\xd9\xe8\t\xca\xc3k\x9f\xb0\x06\x13\xbcE\x17\xbb\x02\x9c:\xffD\x8d\x1f\x85Wv\x14\xfd\x8f\xe3k\xc6\xfe\xf7\x1bu
[Wed Mar 19 12:20:07 2014] [error] [client 173.24.52.209] invalid request-URI
```

Last message of interest from /var/log/mysql/mysqld.err (5 days ago):

```
140314  9:56:02  InnoDB: ERROR: the age of the last checkpoint is 9448765,
InnoDB: which exceeds the log group capacity 9433498.
InnoDB: If you are using big BLOB or TEXT rows, you must set the
InnoDB: combined size of log files at least 10 times bigger than the
InnoDB: largest such row.
```

Versions:

```
# uname -a
Linux myhost 3.3.8-gentoo #1 SMP Fri Sep 28 09:34:42 MYT 2012 i686 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31220 @ 3.10GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

# mysqld -V
140319 12:37:13 [Warning] '--default-character-set' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--character-set-server' instead.
140319 12:37:13 [Warning] '--default-collation' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--collation-server' instead.
mysqld  Ver 5.1.62-log for pc-linux-gnu on i686 (Gentoo Linux mysql-5.1.62-r1)

# apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct 27 2012 19:17:52
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:31
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.3.12
Compiled using: APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.3.12
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"

# php -v
PHP 5.4.6--pl0-gentoo (cli) (built: Oct 27 2012 18:42:24)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Disk appears to have plenty of space still:

```
# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs         960125048 84604800 826748732  10% /
udev               10240        0     10240   0% /dev
/dev/sda3      960125048 84604800 826748732  10% /
tmpfs            1960392      220   1960172   1% /run
rc-svcdir           1024       64       960   7% /lib/rc/init.d
cgroup_root        10240        0     10240   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              1960392        0   1960392   0% /dev/shm
```

Apache processes:

```
# ps -ef|grep -i apache
root      2060     1  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2062  2060  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2066  2060  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2067  2060  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2068  2060  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2069  2060  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2070  2060  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2123  2060  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2124  2060  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2125  2060  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2148  2060  0 10:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
apache    2149  2060  0 10:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
```

Stracing the parent (root) process displays this repeatedly, not sure if it's normal:

```
# strace -p 2060
Process 2060 attached
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 669445}) = 0 (Timeout)
waitpid(-1, 0xbffb4b6c, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED) = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
waitpid(-1, 0xbffb4b6c, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED) = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
waitpid(-1, 0xbffb4b6c, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED) = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
```

The fact that SSH also hangs after a couple thousand bytes indicates that I should be looking wider than Apache. What's the next step to diagnose?

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious from the Apache log that your site was the target of typical exploit scripts that just try to bombard the server with requests for known applications looking for vulnerabilities.

This *may* have led to a compromise - this part is difficult to tell because you haven't detailed what other scripts are running on your machine.

I would suggest running a rootkit analyzer or similar on your server.

Also, this kind of question is better suited for `serverfault.com` as its not related to programming (what stackoverflow is about) but rather system administration/server management.

To prevent such requests from hitting your server, a WAF (Web Application Firewall) or other proxy is recommended which will throttle and block such requests before they reach your machine.

[`naxsi`](http://code.google.com/p/naxsi/wiki/Howto) is a module for nginx that provides an open source WAF.